# What is configured by setting "Log in user automatically" during install?

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, auto-login

I set up a 22.04 desktop system for an elderly relative who lives in another state so I don't have physical access. I administer the system remotely over ssh.

The system was set up during install to log in the user in automatically.  This has worked.

But, how? The documentation (https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-automatic.html.en) says that automatic login needs to be enabled in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

But on this system, it isn't, yet the auto login works.

What, specifically, does the installer do to enable auto login?

Edit - adding requested info

```
$ grep sara /etc/group
adm:x:4:syslog,bill,sara
dialout:x:20:sara
fax:x:21:sara
cdrom:x:24:bill,sara
floppy:x:25:sara
tape:x:26:sara
sudo:x:27:bill,sara
dip:x:30:bill,sara
video:x:44:sara,motion
plugdev:x:46:bill,sara
lpadmin:x:116:bill,sara
sambashare:x:126:bill,sara
sara:x:1001:
```

Comment: Look in `/etc/group`. Do: `grep their_userid /etc/group`.

Comment: @waltinator that listed the groups they are in. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the result of the `grep`

Comment: @waltinator done!

Comment: @OrganicMarble https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en details how autologin can be configured in the GUI. My guess would be that the installer basically does the same thing.

Comment: @vidarlo sure, but my question asks for specifics about what it does.